# Remove previous features from GeoJSON layer on filtering data in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, filter

The following block corresponds to a temporal slider that should update (add and remove) a set of points in a leaflet map.
The code below is **currently working** as I want, it can add the points when the slider is updated. But it **doesn't remove the priveous set**. So whenever I move the slider more than once, the points end up stacking above one another.
I need a way to erase the previous points on the map. And the function I had intended for that   '***pontosVisiveis.clearLayers();***' is not clearly working.
Sorry for comments in portuguese

```
/*Seletor de fotos*/
var range1 = document.getElementById('range1');
var range2 = document.getElementById('range2');

range1.addEventListener('input', updateSlider);
range2.addEventListener('input', updateSlider);
var lastinterval=150


function updateSlider() {
    //controlo dos ranges
    var minValue = parseInt(range1.value);
    var maxValue = parseInt(range2.value);
    var interval
    
    
    interval = maxValue - minValue 

    if (minValue >= maxValue) {
        range1.value = maxValue - 10;
        minValue = parseInt(range1.value); // Atualiza o valor mínimo após a modificação
    } 

    console.log('Min Value:', range1.value,'Max Value:', range2.value,'Intervalo', range2.value-range1.value);

    //preparacao dos pontos da da função
    const todos_os_pontos = ponto_foto; //formato object
        console.log('todos os pontos',todos_os_pontos);
    var length = Object.keys(todos_os_pontos.features).length;
        console.log('Número total de pontos',length);

    var pontosVisiveis = L.geoJSON(todos_os_pontos); //formato geojson
        console.log('pontos visiveis',pontosVisiveis);

    pontosVisiveis.clearLayers();
        console.log('limpou',pontosVisiveis);

    const FilteredFeatures = todos_os_pontos.features.filter(feature => {
        var dataFoto = feature.properties.data_antiga; // Assumindo que 'data_antiga' é a propriedade que contém a data da foto
        return dataFoto >= minValue && dataFoto <= maxValue;
    });
    


    pontosVisiveis=L.geoJSON(FilteredFeatures, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
            layer.bindPopup("<h4> "+ feature.properties.name + 
                "<br>"+
                    "<table>"+
                        "<tr>"+
                            "<th>"+ feature.properties.data_antiga +"    "+ feature.properties.Descricao +"</th>"+
                            "<th>"+ feature.properties.data_nova +"</th>"+
                        "</tr>"+
                        "<tr>"+
                            "<td>"+feature.properties.foto_antiga+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+feature.properties.foto_nova+"</td>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                        "<tr>"+
                            "<td><a href="+ feature.properties.Fonte +" target=_blank"+">Fonte</a>"+
                            "<td>"+"</td>"+
                        "</tr>"+
                    "</table>"
                            

        )},
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
            var corDoMarcador;
            if (feature.properties.Fonte === '' && feature.properties.foto_antiga !=='') {
                // Se não tiver foto antiga ou fonte
                corDoMarcador = '#CB2B3E'; // Vermelho
            } else if (feature.properties.data_antiga !== '' && feature.properties.data_nova === '') {
                // Se data e foto antigas, a fonte estiver preenchidas
                corDoMarcador = '#FFD326'; // Amarelo
            } else if (feature.properties.data_antiga !== '' && feature.properties.data_nova !== '' &&
                        feature.properties.foto_antiga !=='' && feature.properties.foto_nova !== '') {
                // Se tiver ambas as fotos e fonte e dadas (tudo correto)
                corDoMarcador = '#2AAD27'; // Verde
            } else {
                // Se nenhuma das condições acima for atendida, atribua uma cor padrão
                corDoMarcador = '#000000'; // Preto
            }

            return new L.circleMarker(latlng,{
                fillColor: corDoMarcador, // Cor de preenchimento do círculo
                radius: 8, // Raio do círculo
                color: '#000000', // Cor da borda do círculo
                fillOpacity: 0.8, // Opacidade do preenchimento
                weight: 0.5 , //grossura da borda do círculo
            });
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    console.log(FilteredFeatures.length)
    console.log('no mapa', pontosVisiveis);


    //Repor o valor do ultimo intervalo
    lastinterval = interval
    console.log(lastinterval)
};
```

`pontosVisiveis` is the variable that updates the points on the map

Comment: mistake. already edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your approach is that at each call of `updateSlider()` you create a new GeoJSON layer and add it to the map. With `pontosVisiveis.clearLayers()` you then clear the last created layer, not the previous ones.

You can simplify this by creating GeoJSON layer with filter but without any data only once outside the `updateSlider()` function. Then inside the function you just clear the layer and add data which will be automatically filtered, since layer was created with filter.

Code could then look something like this:

```
const todos_os_pontos = ponto_foto; //formato object
var minValue;
var maxValue;

const pontosVisiveis = L.geoJSON(null, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup("<h4> "+ feature.properties.name + 
      "<br>"+
        "<table>"+
          "<tr>"+
            "<th>"+ feature.properties.data_antiga +"    "+ feature.properties.Descricao +"</th>"+
            "<th>"+ feature.properties.data_nova +"</th>"+
          "</tr>"+
          "<tr>"+
            "<td>"+feature.properties.foto_antiga+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+feature.properties.foto_nova+"</td>"+
            "</tr>"+
          "<tr>"+
            "<td><a href="+ feature.properties.Fonte +" target=_blank"+">Fonte</a>"+
            "<td>"+"</td>"+
          "</tr>"+
        "</table>"
  )},
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
    var corDoMarcador;
    if (feature.properties.Fonte === '' && feature.properties.foto_antiga !=='') {
        corDoMarcador = '#CB2B3E'; // Vermelho
    } else if (feature.properties.data_antiga !== '' && feature.properties.data_nova === '') {
        corDoMarcador = '#FFD326'; // Amarelo
    } else if (feature.properties.data_antiga !== '' && feature.properties.data_nova !== '' &&
                feature.properties.foto_antiga !=='' && feature.properties.foto_nova !== '') {
        corDoMarcador = '#2AAD27'; // Verde
    } else {
        corDoMarcador = '#000000'; // Preto
    }
    return new L.circleMarker(latlng,{
        fillColor: corDoMarcador, // Cor de preenchimento do círculo
        radius: 8, // Raio do círculo
        color: '#000000', // Cor da borda do círculo
        fillOpacity: 0.8, // Opacidade do preenchimento
        weight: 0.5 , //grossura da borda do círculo
    });
  },
  filter: function(feature) {
    var dataFoto = feature.properties.data_antiga;
    return dataFoto >= minValue && dataFoto <= maxValue;
  });
}).addTo(map);

function updateSlider() {
  var interval;
  minValue = parseInt(range1.value);
  maxValue = parseInt(range2.value);
  interval = maxValue - minValue;
  if (minValue >= maxValue) {
    range1.value = maxValue - 10;
    minValue = parseInt(range1.value); // Atualiza o valor mínimo após a modificação
  }
  pontosVisiveis.clearLayers();
  pontosVisiveis.addData(todos_os_pontos);

  lastinterval = interval;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked, I and liked your syntax to the various functions